# JSP should redirect to a dynamic URL in a new window or tab

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, pdf, struts

I have a jsp page from which i have to redirect to an external URL and this URL has a dynamic field at the end which i bring from another class. **The task for me is to open this url in a new tab or window when that jsp is loaded**. I tried the target attribute in the HTML tag but it did not work.

```
<html target="_blank">
<body>
<% 
String filename=(String)request.getAttribute("fileToOpen");
response.sendRedirect("http://manuals/example/"+filename+".pdf"); 
%>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

have you tried javascript?

you can put a  tag (which are always loaded before the HTML).

for example (http://jsfiddle.net/yeLpy4st/)

For your case you can use something like

```
<% 
String filename=(String)request.getAttribute("fileToOpen");
%>
<script>
window.open("http://manuals/example/"+<%= filename %>+".pdf", "_blank");
</script>
```

you can also change where you want the new page to open (in this case it's '_blank'), a good reference is [Window open() Method](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) reference from W3Schools

Comment: i tried 'window.open'. That works but the **URL** is not a static one. I have a dynamic URL not the static. So, i have to pass the 'filename' attribute to the URL

Comment: @chandrakanth `<script>
function f(var DynamicLink)
{
window.open(DynamicLink, "_blank");
}
</script>` ?

Comment: or you could print it as a variable. In you case in your case the link can be `"http://manuals/example/"+<%= filename %>+".pdf"`

Answer (score 0):

You could try it with **Javascript** :

```
 window.open('www.newtab.com','_newtab');
```

Comment: Yes. But as i mentioned, i have a dynamic URL not the static. So, i have to pass the 'filename' attribute to the URL

Comment: did you try putting the <%= filename %> in a hidden field and call it from the JavaScript window.open?

Answer (score 0):

I used the 'target' attribute in the anchor tag. I did not use JavaScript because of some application constraints. It worked!